# How to make use of a dtd file to parse xml data?

Tags: java, xml, dtd

I have more than a 1000 xml files with size in 2-3MBs each.  I am using a DOM parser for parsing the xml.  Now I have been provided with dtd file for every xml file.  I dont know how to use the dtd for better parsing.

I did my side of research and found that dtd can be used for validation of an xml file.  If so how can I validate it in Java?  Is there any other use of a dtd file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To validate the xml with DTD you just need to set the validator on true mode.
How to do that?

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setValidating(true);